# Create second database for wordpress to use

Tags: php, database, wordpress

Ok, so my client has a database which has 500+ posts, and he wants me to create the second database where custom post type should place and read data from it.

The reason why is because there will be an option for visitors to come and fill the form that will write in database columns and save as draft post for admin to review. After validation from dashboard admin will publish that post and post will list in custom post type archive page. Custom post type also has custom taxonomy.

How would I go about using a different DB for only those custom post types, for reading and updating?

Comment: Why would or should this need a second database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you could use the multisite functionality in Wordpress
that will provide you the facility to create the tables in the same database but with a different prefix.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but problem is that client insists on second DB